# Как посмотреть все сессии которые запущены?

Tags: node.js, сессия, express

Есть node.js-проект, для работы с сессиями используется express-session.
Как можно вывести в консоль все активные сессии, не использую при этом всякие дополнительные session-storage?

Answer (score 1):

Информация о сессиях хранится на серверной стороне только если вы используете специальные middleware, которые хранят эти данные в базе данных. В этом случае вы можете извлечь эти данные из этой БД. Но даже в этом случае вам будет трудно определить, является ли сессия активной. Поэтому если вам нужно вести учёт активных сессий, то придётся писать свой код для этого. Express из коробки ничего не знает о сессиях. Middleware для сессий ничего не знает от том, как эти данные хранятся (куки, БД или другое).

Comment: Если не брать учет активные, как достать все живые сессии (например у них срок годности 5мин)?